# SCRIPT5045: Assignment to read-only properties is not allowed in strict mode

Tags: javascript

I'm getting **SCRIPT5045: Assignment to read-only properties is not allowed in strict mode** in IE 11 (latest Chrome works fine) in reference to the line

`A.doc.head = A.doc.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0];`.

I'm confused on how to fix it. I've included what should be the relevant code below.

```
(function (win, doc, arg) {
    'use strict';
    var A = win[arg.prefix] = {
        'win': win,
        'doc': doc,
        'arg': arg,
        'stu': {},
        'fun': (function () {
            return {
                init: function () {
                    var scripts = A.doc.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT'),
                        n = scripts.length,
                        i;
                    for (i = 0; i < n; i = i + 1) {
                        if (scripts[i].src.match(A.arg.src)) {
                            A.arg.script = scripts[i];
                            A.arg.options = A.fun.options();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    A.doc.head = A.doc.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0];
                    A.fun.structure();
                },
                // more functions
        }())
    };
    A.fun.init();
}(window, document, {
    'prefix': 'accescape_' + new Date().getTime(),
    'src': '/widget.js',
    'defaults': {
        'language': 'en'
    }
}));
```

Comment: `arg.prefix` is `undefined`, which makes you overwrite the global `undefined` variable??? That should've thrown the first error!

Comment: @Bergi In my attempt to simplify the code and take out irrelevant parts, I deleted those arguments. I have fixed the code above To include `arg.prefix`. Sorry for the Confusion.

Comment: I see, thank you. Though I've already answered the main question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`document.head`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.head) is a read-only property. If you want to shim it for oldIE, you'd better test for its nonexistence first:

```
if (!doc.head)
    doc.head = doc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
```

Comment: Thank you! I was looking at it from a completely different angle and overlooked the fact that `doc.head` already existed. I opted to rename from `doc.head` to `doc.heads`. Thanks again and sorry for the initial confusion.